# django-select2-forms autocomplete options render in admin panel but not in inline form

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I'm using the [django-select2-forms library](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-select2-forms/) and Django 1.11 and the select2 form autosuggests and completes perfectly in the Django admin panel, but on my HTML page it doesn't.

In HTML, i'm inserting my form with:

```
{{forms.media}}
{{forms.tags}}
```

forms.py

```
tags = select2.fields.MultipleChoiceField(Tag,overlay="Choose several skills...")
```

models.py

```
tags = select2.fields.ManyToManyField(Tag,overlay="Choose several skills...",ajax=True,search_field="name")
```

Is my forms.py accurate? The documentation for this library is scarce and I've been working hours on this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just spent a couple of hours trying to figure this one out and came across your question in the process. Figured I'd post the solution:

It seems that django-select2-forms does load all static files for select2 in the default django-admin site because typically the developer would not edit those templates.

However, for our own templates we have to include the CSS and JS ourselves.

Do this by adding {{form.media.css}} in your `<head>` and {{form.media.js}} in the footer of your base.html template or wherever you're bringing in your other CSS and Javascript.

It's astounding that such a crucial step is not mentioned anywhere in the docs for this package.